# covering rectangle with .jpg image in webGL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d, webgl

I'm begginer in webGL world and I'm having some trouble drawing image into rectangle I've made.

First i made shape for rectangle:

```
var posLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "pos");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
var vertices = [
 1.0,  2.0,  0.0, 
-1.0,  2.0,  0.0, 
-1.0, -2.0,  0.0, 
 1.0, -2.0,  0.0  
];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Then i created texture, made it active and made mitmap like this:

```
var texture = null;
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_010.jpg";
image.onload = function() {
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    ...
}
```

In the end I'm unsuccesfully trying to draw all stuff:

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

Here is a full code

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("experimental-webgl");

var str = document.querySelector("#vs").textContent;
var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vs, str);
gl.compileShader(vs);
 
var str = document.querySelector("#fs").textContent;
var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fs, str);
gl.compileShader(fs);

var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vs);
gl.attachShader(program, fs);
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);

var samplerLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "sampler");
gl.uniform1i(samplerLoc, 0);

gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.clearColor(0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 1);

var texture = null;
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_010.jpg";
image.onload = function() {
  var posLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "pos");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
    var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    var vertices = [
       1.0,  2.0,  0.0, 
      -1.0,  2.0,  0.0, 
      -1.0, -2.0,  0.0, 
       1.0, -2.0,  0.0  
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    var indices = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 pos;
attribute vec2 texture;
varying vec2 varyingTexture;

void main(void) {
 gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
 varyingTexture = texture;
}
</script>

<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 varyingTexture;
uniform sampler2D sampler; 
    
void main(void) {
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, varyingTexture);
}
</script>
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: You might find http://webglfundamentals.org helpful in learning more WebGL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the console reveals that you're applying incompatible texture filtering:

```
texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'. Or the texture is Float or Half Float type with linear filtering while OES_float_linear or OES_half_float_linear extension is not enabled.
```

Indeed your textures dimensions are not a power of two(NPOT) so you have to use a texture filter that does not require mipmaps, also you can not generate mipmaps:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
// Use linear filter for minification
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
// removed generate mipmap call
```

Next up you need to set an appropriate wrap mode, for NPOT textures the only compatible wrap mode is `CLAMP_TO_EDGE`:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Then you'll see that the rectangle changed its color, but your vertex data does not contain any texture coordinates so they'll be substituted with `0` everywhere resulting in the color of only the top most pixel to be applied. To fix that you need to get the location of your `texture` attribute and enable the attribute array:

```
var texLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "texture");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texLoc); // Could use 1 directly here
```

The next thing is your vertex data, you're not transforming your vertex positions so you're working with *normalized device coordinates*(NDC) which are from -1 to +1, however you're exceeding this with your coordinates. [Check this link to learn more about coordinate spaces](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html). Creating a screen aligned quad and adding the missing texture coordinates the vertex data looks like this:

```
var vertices = [// \/\/ texture coordinates
   1.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1,0,
  -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0,0,
  -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 0,1,
   1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1,1
];// /\/\/\/\ Fixed positions to lie within NDC
```

Also you're defining four triangles with your index buffer while you just need two to build a quad:

```
var indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0];
```

Finally set your [vertex attribute pointers](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) accordingly:

```
// Note the last two arguments are defined in BYTES
gl.vertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(texLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 12);
```

Result:

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("experimental-webgl");

var str = document.querySelector("#vs").textContent;
var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vs, str);
gl.compileShader(vs);
 
var str = document.querySelector("#fs").textContent;
var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fs, str);
gl.compileShader(fs);

var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vs);
gl.attachShader(program, fs);
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);

var samplerLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "sampler");
gl.uniform1i(samplerLoc, 0);

gl.clearColor(0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 1);

var texture = null;
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_010.jpg";
image.onload = function() {
    // Get and enable vertex attribute for texture, note I renamed "texture" to "tex" in the shader and here
    var posLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "pos");
    var texLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "tex");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
    var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    // Add texture coordinates, fix positions
    var vertices = [
       1.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1,0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0,0,
      -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 0,1,
       1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1,1
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 12);

    var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    // Remove excess indices
    var indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    // Use linear filter for minification
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    // Do not generate mip maps

    // Apply appropriate wrap mode
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 pos;
attribute vec2 tex;
varying vec2 varyingTexture;

void main(void) {
 gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
 varyingTexture = tex;
}
</script>

<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 varyingTexture;
uniform sampler2D sampler; 
    
void main(void) {
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, varyingTexture);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is such an amazing answer && help, very thankful!

Comment: Just to make it complete, what exactly represent this two last numbers in vertices array you made? I expect that first three are floats for x, y and z but the last two? Because I'm trying to cover polygon with this image instead od rectangle now and it kind of doesn't work. You can see there http://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/mqpzfgd0/2/

Comment: That are the texture coordinates used to do [UV mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping), ranging from the bottom left(0,0) to the upper right corner(1,1). Please refer to the tutorials mentioned by @gman for more information.